# joomla 3.1 dropdown in custom component

Tags: html, html-select, joomla3.1

how do I create a dropdown list in joomla 3.1 for a custom component. I try to create custom fields and I would like to use joomlas dropdown with search

my get  input method looks

```
public function getInput() {


        $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;

        $sub_id = $jinput->get('sub_id');

        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true)
                ->select('*')
                ->from('#__unis_faculties')
                //->join('#__unis_subjects')    
                ->order('faculty_name');
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $rows = $db->loadObjectList();

        if (isset($sub_id)) {
            $actual = $db->getQuery(true)
                    ->select('f.id, f.faculty_name')
                    ->from('#__unis_faculties AS f')
                    ->join('LEFT', '#__unis_subjects AS s ON f.id = s.faculty')
                    ->where('f.id = ' . $sub_id);
            $db->setQuery($actual);
            $actual_row = $db->loadRow();
        }
        $html = '';

        $html .= '<div class="span12 input-prepend">
                    <span class="add-on">€ </span>
                    <input class="span4" name="price" id="price" type="text" />
                 </div>';

        $html .= '<field name="" type="list" default="" label="Select an option" description=""><select>';
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $html .= '<option ' . "selected" ? $row->id = $actual_row->id : '' . 'value="' . $row->id . '" >' . $row->faculty_name . '</option>';
        }
        $html .= '</select></field>';
        return $html;
    }
```

but this does not outputs the desired result, the list won't shows up

the actual code is producing the following dropdown but without to show the elements
[image]

Comment: maybe attaching a screenshot of the desired result or posting a jsfiddle with the html generated will help others help you.

Comment: Try removing the `<select>` and `</select>` from your $html